# Strange behavior when SELECT some special characters in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a row, which have column `url` with the following value:

```
http://example.com/a~~1234567890-=!@#$%^&*()_+[\"test\"]
```

When I execute the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE `url` = 'http://example.com/a~~1234567890-=!@#$%^&*()_+[\"test\"]'
```

MySQL says that record is not exists.

Comment: \ might be escaped. Use a \\ to escape the \

Comment: You mean that \ used when escaping " (i.e. \") should be escaped as well?

Comment: Yes, I would try 'h t t p://example.com/a~~1234567890-=!@#$%^&*()_+[\\"test\\"]' (obviously without spaces in h t t p)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the \ in your two \" since \" is an escape sequence: only the quote " will remain in the executed query.

> \" [is an escape sequence turned into a] double quote (“"”) character

> \\ [is an escape sequence turned into a] backslash (“\”) character

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-literals.html

So

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE `url` = 'http://example.com/a~~1234567890-=!@#$%^&*()_+[\\"test\\"]'
```